# Why Firebase is unable to get PlayGames AuthCode and pass it into its Credential?

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication, google-play-games

To begin with, I'm working on a Unity Game where I'm authenticating user when the game starts. My build environment is android. I'm using Firebase [authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/unity/play-games) for Google Play Games Services to authenticate user.

When the game starts in my android device or emulator, it is able to authenticate Play Games Services as well as able to connect with Firebase (I'm getting analytics data). However, when I pass the PlayGames AuthCode into Firebase.Auth Credentials, it stops executing the code (I've debug log for it). It does not throw any error in LogCat except

> Firebase | server_auth_code

I tried searching web for different issues, but nothing. I checked my keys in player setting, firebase settings, OAuth 2.0 credentials on my Google API console and even check keys from my Google Play Console (which I'm not using at this stage). I have even checked my test users email addresses in Game Services and tried multiple google play games account. But issue still persist.

I'm using similar script in my other unity project where authentication works like a charm. I tried to use same script here and ended up with this issue: [here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/622). However, I solved it by removing all the packages and re-importing them into unity and changed my call functions in the script. Now, I'm stuck at this issue.
Here is cs file:

```
using GooglePlayGames;
using GooglePlayGames.BasicApi;
using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class SetFirebase : MonoBehaviour
{
    string authCode;
    void Start()
    {
        PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder().
        RequestServerAuthCode(false /* Don't force refresh */).Build();

        PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);
        PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
        Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) =>
        {
            if (success)
            {
                authCode = PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.GetServerAuthCode();
                Debug.Log("PlayGames successfully authenticated!");
                Debug.Log("AuthCode: " + authCode);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("PlayGames SignIn Failed");
            }
        });

        Firebase.FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            var dependencyStatus = task.Result;
            if (dependencyStatus == Firebase.DependencyStatus.Available)
            {
                Debug.Log("Firebase Ready!!!");
                RunFirebase();
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogError(System.String.Format("Could not resolve all Firebase dependencies: {0}", dependencyStatus));
            }
        });
    }    

    private void RunFirebase(){
        Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth auth = Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
        Debug.Log("init firebase auth ");

        Firebase.Auth.Credential credential = Firebase.Auth.PlayGamesAuthProvider.GetCredential(authCode);
        Debug.Log(" passed auth code ");

        auth.SignInWithCredentialAsync(credential).ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            if (task.IsCanceled)
            {
                Debug.LogError("SignInOnClick was canceled.");
                return;
            }
            if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                Debug.LogError("SignInOnClick encountered an error: " + task.Exception);
                return;
            }
            Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser newUser = task.Result;
            Debug.LogFormat("SignInOnClick: User signed in successfully: {0} ({1})", newUser.DisplayName, newUser.UserId);
        });    
    }
}
```

My LogCat executes everything till *"init firebase auth"* but does not execute *"passed auth code"* so I know there is some issue in passing the credentials. It also does not run anything inside *auth.SignInWithCredentialAsync(credential)*.

Any help or suggestion would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things I may suggest:

1) Replace `ContinueWith` with `ContinueWithOnMainThread`. This is a [Firebase Extension](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/extensions/task-extension) that will guarantee that your logic runs on the main Unity thread (which tends to resolve many Unity specific issues). I go into more detail about that [here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/07/firebase-and-tasks-how-to-deal-with.html).

2) Your logic may have a race condition between the `Authenticate` callback and the `CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync` continuation. These will not necessarily run in the order that you see them in your logic.

If I were building this system, I might prefer using Coroutines and a [custom yield instruction](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CustomYieldInstruction.html):

```
class Authenticate : CustomYieldInstruction
{
    private bool _keepWaiting = true;
    public override bool keepWaiting => _keepWaiting;

    public Authenticate(Social.ILocalUser user) {
        user.Authenticate((bool success)=>{
            /* old authentication code here */
            _keepWaiting = false;
        });
    }

}
```

Then in a coroutine have something like:

```
private IEnumerator InitializeCoroutine() {
    /* old authentication code */

    // I'm ignoring error checking for now, but it shouldn't be hard to figure in.
    // I'm mostly going from memory now anyway

    // start both authentication processes in parallel
    var authenticate = new Authenticate(Social.localUser);
    var firebaseDependenciesTask = FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync();

    // wait on social
    yield return authenticate;

    // wait on Firebase. If it finished in the meantime this should just fall through
    yield return new WaitUntil(()=>firebaseDependenciesTask.IsComplete);

    RunFirebase();
}
```

This way my logic looks roughly synchronous whilst still maintaining the asynchronosity (spell check claims that I made up that word) of the systems you're depending on *and* you avoid threading related issues that arise when using `ContinueWith`.

Let me know if that helps!

--Patrick

Comment: Thanks for the brief explanation, Patrick! Wasn't expecting the mighty pat to reply but here we are! Anyways, so I did try _ContinueWithOnMainThread_ but I was still running into same issue. I also tried _CustomYieldInstruction_  but that opened up a whole new compilation issues as somehow ILocalUser and even localUser stopped getting recognized by Unity. After spending enough time, I have decided to get rid of checking dependencies as of now and that worked for me to get my desired results in Firebase. I might come back to dependencies again but at a later stage. Thanks for looking into this!

Comment: So, the thing with `CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync` is that it only actually does anything on Android (iOS and Desktop, it's basically a no-op). Further, on Android it doesn't do anything if the player already has the latest version of the Google Play Services. Just make sure you add "test on device/simulator without/with an outdated version of the Google Play Services" to your release checklist so you don't forget about it (or know that some % of your playerbase may crash without explanation).

Comment: You can also call `CheckDependencies` synchronously, but you can't fix them synchronously ( https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/firebase-app#class_firebase_1_1_firebase_app_1a3cdbb6dc40eaa7a1c07813c59f18e6d2 ). This still will block on the main thread (there is also a `CheckDependenciesAsync`, but you might as well call `CheckAndFix` if you've fixed your threading issues) and won't fix any detected issues (prompt a player to update Google Play Services), but maybe it's safer than doing nothing.